# Finding roots using $\displaystyle\int_0^1(1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx=\int_0^2(1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following relation-

> $$\displaystyle\int_0^1(1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx=\int_0^2(1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx $$ 
>   $$\text{then what is the interval in which the root of the equation}\space ax^2+bx+c=0\space\text{lie?}$$

Where $a,b,c$ are non-zero numbers.

I think one should apply mean value theorem here. But I can't proceed. What to do?

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole equation and question exactly as written and that the two integrals are not also equal to zero? You have revealed in comments (and could usefully state in the question) what the expected answer is.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1(1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx=\int_0^2(1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\int_0^1(1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx - \bigg(\int_0^1 (1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx $$
$$+ \int_1^2 (1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx \bigg)= 0$$
$$=$$
$$\int_1^2(1+\cos^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx=0$$

Observe that :

$$1+\cos^8(x) >0 \; \forall  \; x\in \mathbb R \; \text{since} \; -1 \leq \cos x \leq1 $$

But, since $1+\cos^8(x) > 0$ and the integral equals to zero, what can you conclude about $ax^2 + bx + c$ in the interval $[1,2]$ which the integral is defined to be zero ?

Comment: It changes sign once so that the net algebraic area becomes zero. Isn't it?

Comment: @tatan Correctly, there lies a solution in the interval $[1,2]$.

Comment: Agreed... then the answer should be [1,2] right?

Comment: Yes ! Also do not use the real analysis tag, that's a different field. Same as means !

Comment: But the answer says - "one root between 0 and 1 and the other between 1 and 2"... we didn't get the first case.right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $p(x)\gt 0$ for all $x$ and $$\int_m^np(x)f(x)dx=0$$ what can you say about $f(x)$ in the interval $[m,n]$?

Comment: Is it $f(x)$ changes sign once between $[m,n]$?

Comment: @tatan No - that's not quite it, but what happens if $f(x)$ does not change sign at all?

Comment: Sorry... I can't figure it out

Comment: If f(x) doesn't change sign the both f(x) and p(x) should be >0...

Comment: @tatan Or $f(x)$ could be negative throughout so the integrand has the same sign over the whole interval. So how can the integral be zero?

Comment: I still can't figure it out really...

Comment: @tatan Well if the integrand is positive over an interval of positive length, the integral will be positive; and if the integrand is negative the integral will be negative (here there is no problem about anything being defined, all the functions are nice). So the integrand must change sign at least once in the interval. Now one component is positive throughout, so the other must change sign at least once. Consider the interval $[1,2]$ fro your particular problem.

Comment: Right... so it should be [1,2] ... but my book says that [0,1] also has a root...  are we missing out something?